# Ruby on Rails Server Times Out When Exceptions are Raised

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, puma

Sometimes when an exception is thrown by my Ruby on Rails app, the network request fails to respond. Other clients are still able to connect to the server, but the server responds notably slower. If I `CMD+C` to kill the server, suddenly the exception appears in the console as the server shuts down (owing to a `puts` statement I have in my code inside my default exception handler in my base controller).

For example:
`<NoMethodError> undefined method 'where' for #<Array:0x007f9555b7f380>`

Normally I'd assume my exception handler had blocked the process, but the issue is sporadic and furthermore the exception backtrace correctly points to the line which caused the above exception. There's also this message in the console when I terminate:

```
2017-07-06 05:09:13 -0700: Read error: #<IOError: closed stream>
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/reactor.rb:182:in `write'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/reactor.rb:182:in `<<'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/reactor.rb:182:in `block in add'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/reactor.rb:180:in `synchronize'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/reactor.rb:180:in `add'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:450:in `process_client'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/server.rb:299:in `block in run'
/Users/zaneclaes/.rvm/gems/ruby-2.3.0/gems/puma-3.8.2/lib/puma/thread_pool.rb:120:in `block in spawn_thread'
```

Though I'm unclear if this is just from the abnormal server shutdown, or a symptom of the same problem. Using Ruby `2.3.0` and Rails `5.0.2`.

Comment: This happened to my once, When I had a filter in that page. The filter was requesting much data and it was many fields and each time I tried to filter anything, I had the same issue. Maybe something to look in